# Kentico 9 transformation page/file URL

Tags: kentico

In my custom page type, you can select an uploaded file. That's fine, but in my ascx transformation, i'm having a hard time getting the URL. The field is 'Process'.

Here's what i currently have.

```
<%# IfEmpty(Eval("Process"),"N/A","<a href=" + Eval("Process") +" target='blank' class='icon download'>Download</a>")%>
```

When rendered, the html is this:

```
<a href="214b6876-cb39-4a58-813f-19dcb7c788e4" target="blank" class="icon download">Download</a>
```

I'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either of the 2 methods below.  Both have their downfalls though.

`<a href="<%# GetFileUrl("Process", "Something") %>"Link here<a/>` this will

Downfall with this is if there is no value in the "Process" field, it will return an invalid URL.  So I tend to use something a little better (but not much)

`<a href="/getattachment/<%# ValidationHelper.GetGuid(Eval("Process"), Guid.Empty) %>/<%# ValidationHelper.GetString(Eval("NodeAlias"), "download") %>">Item to download</a>`

This will create a valid URL with some invalid properties to it.  Meaning if there is no value in the Process field, it will return `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`.  If the NodeAlias field is empty, it will return "download".  So again, not 100% fool-proof but it works well in most cases.

**Update**
Check out this link:
https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/options-for-file-fields-in-structured-data

I think the piece you need in here is in the "CMS.File page type" section:
`<a href="<%#GetDocumentUrl("FileField ", "kenticopicture")%>">This is the link to the picture</a>`

Comment: I had first tried GetFileUrl, but it isn't an attachment. When i use this: GetFileUrl("Process")I get this `/getattachment/214b6876-cb39-4a58-813f-19dcb7c788e4/Page-One.aspx`, which give me 404. The perm URL is: /getdoc/214b6876-cb39-4a58-813f-19dcb7c788e4/BadgerCatalog.aspx. Page-one.aspx is my custom page type. Maybe a small tweek to your second method will work.

Comment: Ok that helps a bit more, take a look at the update to my answer.

Comment: thanks. I'm closer. I just need to get the file name, rather than 'kentiopicture.aspx'

Comment: Ok, so i went back to my custom page type, , changed the form control to URL Selector. in my transformation i now have this `<%# IfEmpty(Eval("Process"),"N/A","<a href=" + Eval("Process") +" target='blank' class='icon download'>Download</a>")%>`. In the browser, i get this `<a href="/Resource-Centre/Call-Center-Services/Test/complaint_form.aspx" target="blank" class="icon download">Download</a>`. This seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [transformation methods reference](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/reference-transformation-methods#Reference-Transformationmethods-Images)

You can use <%#GetImage(Eval("Process"))%>.  This will return an Image tag. There are a couple other parameters for sizing if you want to use those.

Comment: It isn't an image i've linking to, but an uploaded PDF. AS this is then a cms.file page type, I thought using GetDocumentURL would work, but i'm not getting the actual node name.

Answer (score 0):

See the "[Transformation reference](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/developing-websites/loading-and-displaying-data-on-websites/writing-transformations/reference-transformation-methods)" link on your Trasnformation editor, it goes to all the available transformation methods you can use.

In it it shows:

This will generate an actual image tag.  If however you want a link, it usually is

/getattachment/<%# Eval("TheImage")%>/ImageFileNameCanBeAnythingThough.jpg

example:
/getattachment/1936c69d-a28c-428a-90a7-09154918da0f/Christmas.jpg